# Github Actions: How to share bash aliases across steps?

Tags: bash, github, github-actions

I am using the following workflow to test out bash aliases. I have defined a bash alias called `lll` in the first step that I am trying to re-use in the next step. However, the workflow fails in the second step as the `lll` is not found. So, is there a way to share aliases across steps?

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  release:
    types:
      - created

jobs:
  ossie_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Audit Python dependencies 
    steps:
      - name: Print a greeting
        run: |
          shopt -s expand_aliases
          alias lll=ls
          echo 'alias lll=ls' >> ~/.bashrc
          lll
      - name: Test alias
        shell: bash {0}
        run: |
          shopt -s expand_aliases
          source ~/.bashrc
          lll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Github Actions the default `~/.bashrc` has this in the beginning:

```bash
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

So `source ~/.bashrc` basically does nothing since it's not in an interactive shell.

You can use a tmp file like this:

```yaml
steps:
  - shell: bash
    run: |
      rc=/tmp/rcfile
      echo 'shopt -s expand_aliases' > $rc
      echo 'alias ll="ls -l" ' >> $rc

  - shell: bash
    run: |
      source /tmp/rcfile
      ll
```

Comment: `bashrc` isn't really a kind of file; it's just the specific name of the file sourced by an interactive `bash` shell on startup. So it's not a "tmp bashrc file"; it's just a shell script that you will source.

Comment: @chepner ok. may make more sense to call it just rc file.